# How prove $\max\lbrace \cot{A}(\cot{Y}+\cot{Z}),\cot{B}(\cot{Z}+\cot{X}),\cot{C}(\cot{X}+\cot{Y})\rbrace\ge\frac{2}{3}$

Tags: inequality

> let $\Delta ABC,\Delta XYZ$ are  acute triangle
>
> show that
> $$\max\lbrace\cot{A}(\cot{Y}+\cot{Z}),\cot{B}(\cot{Z}+\cot{X}),\cot{C}(\cot{X}+\cot{Y})\rbrace\ge\dfrac{2}{3}$$

My idea: since
$$\cot{Y}+\cot{Z}=\dfrac{\cos{Y}}{\sin{Y}}+\dfrac{\cos{Z}}{\sin{Z}}=\dfrac{\sin{Z}\cos{Y}+\sin{Y}\cos{Z}}{\sin{Y}\sin{Z}}=\dfrac{\sin{(Y+Z)}}{\sin{Y}\sin{Z}}=\dfrac{\sin{X}}{\sin{Y}\sin{Z}}$$
so
$$a=\cot{A}(\cot{Y}+\cot{Z})=\cot{A}\dfrac{\sin{X}}{\sin{Y}\sin{Z}}$$
and the simaler we have
$$b=\cot{B}(\cot{Y}+\cot{Z})=\dfrac{\cot{C}\sin{Y}}{\sin{X}\sin{Z}},c=\cot{C}(\cot{X}+\cot{Y})=\cot{C}\dfrac{\sin{Z}}{\sin{X}\sin{Y}}$$
so
$$abc=\dfrac{cot{A}\cot{B}\cot{C}}{\sin{X}\sin{Y}\sin{Z}}$$

since  we kow
$$\cot{A}\cot{B}\cot{C}\ge\sqrt{3},\sin{X}\sin{Y}\sin{Z}\le\dfrac{3\sqrt{3}}{8}$$
so
$$abc\ge \dfrac{8}{3}$$

so
$$\max\lbrace a,b,c\rbrace\ge\dfrac{2\sqrt{3}}{3}\ge\dfrac{2}{3}$$

My methods is true?

This problem is also from China South East Mathematical Olympiad

Comment: you can show sum $\geq 2$

Comment: Looks right to me.